# How many 6 hour learning session did the Vilna Gaon have every day?

Tags: torah-study, vilna-gaon

I came up with my own schedule for myself. The best I could do was two options:

1. Wake up at 5am or 5:30am. Daven Shacharis. Learn from 7:00am to 1:00am. Daven Mincha. Exercise for an hour. Rest up a little. Learn from 3:30 till 9:30. Daven Ma'ariv. Learn a little more. Sleep from 10:00pm or 10:30pm till 5:30am.
2. Wake up at 7am or 8am. Daven Shacaris. Learn from 9:00am till 3:00pm. Do Whatever, Daven Mincha and Maariv, Exercise etc. Learn from 6:30 pm till 12:30am. Sleep from 12:30am till 7:30.

I would like to know if a schedule is possible to fit 3 six hour sedarim. As the Gra barely slept what did his schedule look like. I don't want theoretical answers. I want answers that are specific and thought out. If anyone has other alternate schedules for 2 six hour sedarim  or perhaps schedules to fit the 3 - 4 hours of work in there as well like the gaon recommends (3 hours of work. 4 hours in times of need, maximum) that would be great as well. I want specific and practical answers please!
Thanks All!

Comment: see this https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131776/what-did-the-vilna-gaons-study-schedule-look-like

Comment: Don't try to be the Vilna Gaon. Try to be the best version of  yourself. Every person's optimal schedule is different.